# Optimizing Parse to query for new objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, parse-platform, pfquery

I am using Parse as the backend for an app I'm working on. I was wondering if there is an optimal algorithm to query for only 'unseen' new objects.

What I am planning on doing is something like adding a user to the viewed object's relation and later querying all objects to check for the absence of the user. This seems to be O(n* all users who have seen an 'n') complexity which is a bit too much.

Another way to do this is to add the object to a user's key 'seen' and to then query for all objects the user has not seen.

Maybe a much more efficient way could be (assuming I view these objects chronologically) is to mark the first and last objects I see, and only show ones before or after those points using the createdAt key. Then I guess to show new objects outward from those points to not have to divide into multiple queries.

Ideally I'd like to shuffle through the objects, but I also would like to keep this algorithm as efficient as possible.

Comment: Try the date approach and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Create a Class called View. Each View consists of a unique identifier from a viewable Object (CANNOT BE THE OBJECTID) and a pointer to the User that viewed the object.

Your query should be:

```
//(Simple equalTo query)
Query1 = All View Objects where User pointer = User

//(whereKey:that-unique-id-column doesNotMatchKey:that-unique-id-column inQuery:Query1)
Query2 = All viewable Objects where not included in pointers in Query1
```

Comment: I have a couple questions in this approach. Are you saying to create a pointer in the View class for each user that views an object, or just one relation for each View containing all the user pointers? (how many users could use this without hitting Parse.com's 128 KB limit for the PFObject?) Also for for the View class why can't i use the viewableObject's objectId? Then do `all viewable objects whereKey:objectId doesNotMatchKey:viewObjectId inQuery: Query1`
where `viewObjectId` for each row is `viewableObject.objectId`